# Automatic generated move operations and raw pointer members

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, move

Consider a `MemoryMappedFile` class, with the following data members:

```
class MemoryMappedFile
{
....
private:
    // RAII wrapper to some OS-specific raw handle (e.g. Win32 HANDLE),
    // representing the memory-mapped file.
    Handle m_handle;

    // Pointer to file begin (first file byte).
    BYTE* m_first;

    // Pointer to file end (one byte past last file byte).
    BYTE* m_last;
};
```

The `Handle` class is some RAII wrapper to some specific OS raw C-like handle (e.g. think of Win32 `HANDLE`). It is not copyable, but it is *movable*.
Instead, `m_first` and `m_last` are *raw* pointers inside the memory area mapped with the file content.

I'd like the `MemoryMappedFile` class to be *movable* (but not copyable, just like the `Handle` class).

If it weren't for the raw pointers, according to C++11's rules of *automatic* generation of move constructor by member-wise moves, the class would be *automatically* movable.

Unfortunately, the raw pointers force me to write a custom move constructor:

```
MemoryMappedFile::MemoryMappedFile(MemoryMappedFile&& other)
    : m_handle( std::move(other.m_handle) )
{
    // Move m_first
    m_first = other.m_first;
    other.m_first = nullptr;

    // Move m_last
    m_last = other.m_last;
    other.m_last = nullptr;
}
```

It would be nice if C++ standard library had some form of "dumb-as-opposed-to-smart but movable" pointer, with zero-overhead, just like raw pointers (which are fine as *observing* non-owning pointers), but with move operations (move constructor and move assignment) defined, such that the compiler can automatically generate correct move operations in classes that have these pointers as data members.

Is there something like this in C++ standard library, or in Boost?

Or is there any other way to achieve the same goal (beside writing my own custom ObservingPointer class, wrapping raw pointers and defining move operations)?

Comment: What about `std::unique_ptr`?  It's zero overhead, non-copyable, movable, and you can give it a custom deleter if you don't want auto-`delete` on destruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently need a "smart" pointer that is both copyable and movable, but has a well-defined moved-from state, so I wrote [`tidy_ptr`](https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/tidy_ptr.h) which is a "dumb" smart pointer that does nothing special except zero itself on move.  That type is copyable, so to get the semantics you want for your class you would still need to define the copy operations as deleted (or just use `std::unique_ptr` with a no-op deleter).

I've tried to convince the standards committee that [`observer_ptr`, "the world's dumbest smart pointer",](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) should have this behaviour, but the consensus was that it should behave just like a built-in pointer (except for zero-initialization in the constructor). I still think it should zero on move.  That paper shows a `non_owning_ptr` which is an alias for `unique_ptr` with a no-op deleter, which does what you want.

Comment: I believe `observer_ptr` should be zeroed out after a move, just like it happens for `string`, `vector`, etc. Making `observer_ptr`'s move behavior the same of copy behavior doesn't make sense to me. Thanks for sharing your `tidy_ptr` class.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that `string` or `vector` is empty after a move. They are left in a _valid but unspecified_ state. Certain types such as `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_lock`, `future` (and my `tidy_ptr`) provide a stronger guarantee of being in a known state after a move, containers do not guarantee that.

Comment: Before reading your comment, I believed that after a move `string` and `vector` would be in a safe empty state (e.g. `vector.empty() == true`).

Comment: I believe it is better to get zero-after-move operation in a specific wrapper rather than `observer_ptr`. I implemented a generic `NullablePointer` wrapper [here](https://bitbucket.org/FrankHB/yslib/src/c6e512304cd52ec55d194a843686b9cc7dc8baaf/YBase/include/ystdex/pointer.hpp?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#pointer.hpp-48) named `nptr`. Note it does _NOT_ require the underlying pointer to be a builtin pointer type. It is trivial to use `template<T> using tidy_ptr = nptr<observer_ptr<T>>;` then.

Comment: @FrankHB, yeah I had a more generic version of `tidy_ptr` that worked with anything default constructible, not just raw pointers. I'm not sure where that code is now.

Comment: BTW, have the committee considered the ABI issue? Is it harder to make such a wrapper optimized like a raw pointer (as a function parameter) than `observer_ptr` with trivial constructors?

Comment: @FrankHB, yes, a non-trivial move constructor changes how it must be passed to/from functions, but I don't remember that being something the committee was particularly concerned with. The discussion was about what the preferred semantics should be.

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `std::unique_ptr` with your own `noop_deleter`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I have to say this to me seems kind of an "hack", in the sense that I usually associate `std::unique_ptr` to a _unique_ **ownership**, so it is kind of misleading to have a `unique_ptr` that behaves just like an _observing_ pointer (and has a NOOP deleter)...

Comment: @Mr.C64: So give it a name that doesn't imply ownership, e.g. `template <typename T> using movable_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, noop_deleter>;`

Comment: `non_owning_ptr` is an even better name, that makes it _really_ clear there's no ownership :) (That's the name used in [N3840](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf))

Comment: `ownership_agnostic_pointer_that_zeroes_itself_on_move` is more descriptive, but I think `smart_pointer_thats_just_like_a_raw_pointer_except_sets_itself_to_null_when_moved_from` better captures programmer intent.