# Why isn't observer_ptr zeroed after a move?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, move

Why isn't the [`observer_ptr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf) zeroed after a move operation?

It is correctly set to `nullptr` in its default construction, and that does make sense (and prevents pointing to garbage).

And, accordingly, it should be zeroed when `std::move()`'d from, just like `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.

This would make it a good candidate in several contexts where raw pointers make sense, as well as *automatic* generation of move operations on classes with raw pointer data members, like in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22307223/1629821).

---

**EDIT**

As @JonathanWakely pointed out in the comments (and that is related to the [aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22307223/1629821)):

> if `observer_ptr` was null after a move it can be used to implement
>   the Rule of Zero for types that have a pointer member. It's a very
>   useful feature.

Comment: Why *should* it be zeroed? It isn't supposed to own the thing it points to.

Comment: It costs more to zero it than to not do so, and you shouldn't be relying on a moved-from value anyway.

Comment: Wow, `observer_ptr` looks like the most ridiculous proposal I've seen.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It doesn't own the thing, right, in fact it must not DELETE it. I'm talking about just setting its value to `nullptr`.

Comment: @AlanStokes: I completely disagree. A moved from object should be in a safe state.

Comment: @AlanStokes, you can't say that for all types. For some types such as `unique_ptr`, `unique_lock` and `future` you absolutely should rely on a moved-from value, otherwise you get multiple owners! For user-defined types with non-owning pointers it is very useful to have a null-after-move "dumb" pointer type, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/22307926/981959

Comment: Zeroing a moved thing suggests that the ownership of the thing hs been transferred. But there is no ownership to transfer, so it makes no sense to zero out.

Comment: @juanchopanza, if `observer_ptr` was null after a move it can be used to implement the Rule of Zero for types that have a pointer member. It's a very useful feature. Any type which has a pointer member and does something to it in the destructor if the pointer is non-null could use a `tidy_ptr` (c.f. `unique_lock`, ScopeGuard-like types etc.)

Comment: @JonathanWakely: exactly!

Comment: As I just commented on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22307926/981959) you are mistaken about `std::string` and `std::vector`.

There is no guarantee that `string` or `vector` is empty after a move. They are left in a _valid but unspecified_ state. Certain types such as `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `unique_lock` and `future` provide a stronger guarantee of being in a known state after a move, containers do not guarantee that.

Comment: @JonathanWakely That would be useful, but I had the feeling it wasn't intended for that kind of thing. On the other hand, I cannot see much use for it in it current proposed form.

Comment: @juanchopanza, its current use is to be explicit that you're passing a non-owning pointer, which is useful because it's not clear what `void f(X*)` intends to do with the pointer (will it take ownership?) That's useful. I just think it would be more useful if it also had one additional property and was null-after-move, otherwise I need _another_ dumb smart pointer which is exactly the same except for being null-after-move.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I agree, and I understand the motivation. But with the zeroing move it couldn't be used in further dumb, observer types that do *not* require clever stuff to happen when moved. But maybe the need for that super-dumb smart pointer is less pressing than for the one you describe.

Comment: @juanchopanza, I can't think of any useful types that _require_ a pointer to have its old value post-move, but if you want that then use a built-in pointer type.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Me neither, but given the way the thing is explained in the proposal, I wouldn't *expect* it to zero on move. All I am saying is that this behaviour seems self-consistent to me, not that it is the most useful dumb smart pointer. I would have more use for your `tidy_ptr`, for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like many people miss the point and the utility of this idea at first.

Consider:

```
template<typename Mutex>
class unique_lock
{
  Mutex* pm;

public:
  unique_lock() : pm() { }

  unique_lock(Mutex& m) : pm(&m) { }

  ~unique_lock() { if (pm) pm->unlock(); }

  unique_lock(unique_lock&& ul) : pm(ul.pm) { ul.pm = nullptr; }

  unique_lock& operator=(unique_lock&& ul)
  {
    unique_lock(std::move(ul)).swap(*this);
    return *this;
  }

  void swap(unique_lock& ul) { std::swap(pm, ul.pm); }
};
```

With a "dumb" smart pointer that is null-on-default-construction and null-after-move you can default three of the special member functions, so it becomes:

```
template<typename Mutex>
class unique_lock
{
  tidy_ptr<Mutex> pm;

public:
  unique_lock() = default;                            // 1

  unique_lock(Mutex& m) : pm(&m) { }

  ~unique_lock() { if (pm) pm->unlock(); }

  unique_lock(unique_lock&& ul) = default;            // 2

  unique_lock& operator=(unique_lock&& ul) = default; // 3

  void swap(unique_lock& ul) { std::swap(pm, ul.pm); }
};
```

That's why it's useful to have a dumb, non-owning smart pointer that is null-after-move, like [`tidy_ptr`](https://gitlab.com/redistd/redistd/blob/master/include/redi/tidy_ptr.h)

But `observer_ptr` is only null-on-default-construction, so if it is standardized it will be useful for declaring a function to take a non-owning pointer, but it won't be useful for classes like the one above, so I'll still need *another* non-owning dumb pointer type. Having two non-owning dumb smart pointer types seems almost worse than having none!

Comment: I marked this as "answer". It seems that the current proposal of `observer_ptr` didn't consider the useful aspects you pointed out here. I can't find any valid rationale for current `observer_ptr` proposal so far.

Comment: The proposal describes the rationale.

Answer (score 2):

So, move constructors are designed to make copy constructors cheaper in certain cases.

Let's write out what we'd expect these constructors and destructors to be: *(This is a bit of a simplification, but that's fine for this example)*.

```
observer_ptr() {
    this->ptr == nullptr;
}

observer_ptr(T *obj) {
    this->ptr = obj;
}

observer_ptr(observer_ptr<T> const & obj) {
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
}

~observer_ptr() {
}
```

You're suggesting that the class provides a move constructor that looks like:

```
observer_ptr(observer_ptr<T> && obj) {
    this->ptr = obj.ptr;
    obj.ptr = null;
}
```

When I would suggest that the existing copy constructor will work fine as is, and is cheaper than the suggested move constructor.

### What about `std::vector` though?

A std::vector, when copied, actually copies the array that it backs. So, a std::vector copy constructor looks something like:

```
vector(vector<T> const & obj) {
    for (auto const & elem : obj)
        this->push_back(elem);
}
```

The move constructor for the std::vector can optimize this. It can do this because that memory can be stolen from `obj`. In a std::vector, this is actually useful to do.

```
vector(vector<T> && obj) {
    this->data_ptr = obj.data_ptr;
    obj.data_ptr = nullptr;
    obj.size = 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, though I suggest using `nullptr` instead of `null` in C++11.

Comment: Besides the cheapness or not of the move operation, it wouldn't make sense semantically. The observer_ptr is just that. It has no interest in or knowledge of the lifetime of the pointee. It exists merely for documentation purposes.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wouldn't these properties given, make it better a `std::weak_ptr<T>`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::weak_ptr` is "too clever": it allows you to check validity, and get shared ownership.

Comment: @juanchopanza _'`std::weak_ptr` is "too clever"'_ that made me laugh actually :-D ...

Comment: _"So, move constructors are designed to make copy constructors cheaper in certain cases."_ That's one use, but not the only one. They also allow non-copyable things to be passed by value, e.g. `std::thread`, `std::unique_ptr`, `std::future` etc. and all of those things rely on being empty after a move.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the minor performance impact of zeroing the moved-from `observer_ptr`, which is easily worked around (copy instead of move), the main rationale was probably to mimic the behaviour of regular pointers as closely as possible, following the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

However, there is a potentially far more significant performance issue: defaulting the move functions allows an `observer_ptr` to be [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable). Trivial copyability allows an object to be copied using `std::memcpy`. If `observer_ptr` were not trivially copyable, neither would any classes with an `observer_ptr` data member, resulting in a performance penalty that cascades down the compositional class hierarchy.

I have no idea what kind of performance improvements can be gained by using the `std::memcpy` optimization, but they're probably more significant than the aforementioned minor performance issue.